# How to use Intent ACTION_SEND in a fragment for sharing the app?

Tags: android, android-fragments

```
public void shareApp() { 
    Intent share = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    share.setType("text/plain");
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "My App");
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "share this");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share via!")); 
}
```

Comment: Please explain what "Code not working" means.

Comment: I am using the above code in a fragment class ..but it is returning the same screen , not showing sharing intent option

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this library which worked well for me :

https://github.com/TimotheeJeannin/AppRate

Simple to use and customise.

Comment: Thanks.. But I'm looking for share app feature in a fragment